# send sms with perl and google voice

Tags: perl, google-voice

I try to send sms to my mobile phone with perl and google voice.

I have installed google::voice module with perl :

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Google::Voice"
```

perl script:

```
use Google::Voice;
my $g = Google::Voice->new->login('my_account', 'my_password');
#send the text!
$g->send_sms('phone_number' => 'message to send');    #line 4
```

I got this error

```
Can't call method "send_sms" on an undefined value at sms.pl line 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

```
login

Login. Returns object on success, false on failure.
```

So it looks like the login failed. Please don't omit the error checking before asking.